# g_hash_table_insert seems to be overriding previously inserted values

Tags: c, hashtable, glib

I am new to the GLIB library. `g_hash_table_insert()` seems to be overriding previously inserted values. When I make a print out of both keys and values of saved data, the keys are still unique and unchanged but the values are **ALL** the same. I am storing a `struct` type into the `GHashtable` and this is its structure:

```
struct _DsectionEntity {
  ...
  int entity_type;
  int sequence_number;
  ...
};

typedef struct _DsectionEntity DsectionEntity;
```

I parse an IGES model file line by line and create `DsectionEntity` object after parsing 2 lines of the D section of the IGES file. I use the sequence number of the object as a key and the entire object as the value. The code for creating the hash table and insertion of values is as follows:

```
void
get_dsection(IgesFile *fp, DsectionEntity *ds)
{
  char *line1 = malloc(91);
  char *line2 = malloc(91);

  /* dsection_ht GHashtable declared as a global var and initialized to NULL */
  dsection_ht = g_hash_table_new_full(g_direct_hash, g_direct_equal, NULL, g_free);

  line1 = get_line(fp, line1);
  while (line1) {
    if (line1[72] == 'D') {
      line2 = get_line(fp, line2);

      /* create Object */
      parser_dsection_new(ds, line1, line2);

      /* insert Object into the hashtable */
      parser_add_ds_object(dsection_ht, ds);
      line1 = get_line(fp, line1);
    } else {
      line1 = get_line(fp, line1);
    }
  }
}
```

The code for inserting:

```
void
parser_add_ds_object(GHashTable * ht, DsectionEntity *dsec_entity)
{
  // printf("KEY : %d\n", GPOINTER_TO_INT(GINT_TO_POINTER(dsec_entity->sequence_number)));
  // printf("SQ : %d\n", dsec_entity->sequence_number);
  // printf("Entity : %d\n", dsec_entity->entity_type);
  // printf("\n");
  g_hash_table_insert(ht, GINT_TO_POINTER(dsec_entity->sequence_number), (gpointer)dsec_entity);
}
```

If comments are removed on `printf`, output(WHICH IS CORRECT) is:
[image]

```
void
print_values(gpointer key, gpointer value, gpointer userdata)
{
  int realkey = GPOINTER_TO_INT(key);
  DsectionEntity *realvalue = (DsectionEntity *)value;

  printf("KEY : %d\n", realkey);
  printf("SQ : %d\n", realvalue->sequence_number);
  printf("Entity : %d\n", realvalue->entity_type);
  printf("====================================\n");
}
```

If I display using `g_hash_table_foreach(dsection_ht, print_values, NULL)` and `print_values()` shown above. I get:
[image]

The object with the repeated `sequence_number` and `entity_type` is the last one added into the `GHashtable` (shown in image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmPB4.png)). Valgrind shows no error, so what could be the problem?

File Format is IGES (INITIAL GRAPHICS EXCHANGE SPECIFICATION). Code for `parser_dsection_new()`:

```
void
parser_dsection_new(DsectionEntity *dsec_entity, char *line1, char *line2)
{
  char substr[10];

  get_field(line1, substr, 1, 8);
  dsec_entity->entity_type = utils_to_int(substr);

  // ...

  get_field(line1, substr, 74, 8);
  dsec_entity->sequence_number = utils_to_int(substr);

  get_field(line1, substr, 9, 8);
  dsec_entity->line_weight = utils_to_int(substr);

  get_field(line1, substr, 17, 8);
  dsec_entity->color = utils_to_int(substr);

  get_field(line1, substr, 57, 8);
  dsec_entity->entity_label = substr;
  // ...
}
```

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I don't understand what you mean by 2 objects.

Comment: @Minathe: Please update your file format along with the definition of `parser_dsection_new` function.

Comment: @Minathe: Can you check the return value of `g_hash_table_insert` whether it is `TRUE` or `FALSE`? You may need to move those prints inside the `if` to check e.g. `if ( g_hash_table_insert(...) == TRUE ) { /* print values */ }`.

Comment: @Azeem OUTPUT is LIKE IMAGE 1 https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmPB4.png All values are printed correctly.

Comment: @Minathe: So, the insertion was successful! The only plausible reason seems to be that you're using only one object of `DsectionEntity` type for parsing and inserting data. But, looking at different examples (e.g. https://gist.github.com/bert/265933/e92f8c3f70a4643e0eed09e52bb726d8da35576b#file-use_hash_table-c-L51), it is evident that the programmer is responsible for creating the copy of the key and value. In your case, the struct type is always the same. Can you try to populate only one key/value pair and insert it? And, then change the pointer without insertion and print the values.

Comment: You are right the cause is overriding the pointer value. Since its a pointer the address it points to doesn't change so when I add a new value it is stored in the shared address hence last insert is populated to all objects.

Comment: @Minathe: Right. You need to keep track of all the `DsectionEntity` types that you want to insert in the hash (See this comment: https://gist.github.com/bert/265933/e92f8c3f70a4643e0eed09e52bb726d8da35576b#gistcomment-1959268).

Comment: The example in the link is a string type so g_strdup work. Is there a a glib func for creating a copy of a gpointer or I have to malloc a local var and copy

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178624/discussion-between-azeem-and-minathe).

Comment: SOLVED!!! Added `ds = (DsectionEntity *) malloc(sizeof(DsectionEntity));` after `parser_add_ds_object(dsection_ht, ds);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the reference of [`g_hash_table_insert()`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Hash-Tables.html#g-hash-table-insert):

> Inserts a new key and value into a GHashTable.
>
> **If the key already exists in the GHashTable its current value is replaced with the new value.** If you supplied a value_destroy_func when creating the GHashTable, the old value is freed using that function. If you supplied a key_destroy_func when creating the GHashTable, the passed key is freed using that function.

So, the `g_hash_table_insert()` API is supposed to replace the existing value with the new one.

---

But, your problem is that you are using only one instance of `DsectionEntity` for everything i.e. parsing, inserting, etc. whereas you ought to have a unique instance every time you want to insert a new key/value pair in the hash. In your code, the same instance is overwritten that's why you're seeing the latest value only. Use unique instances and it will work.

You can use default delete functions in [`g_hash_table_new_full()`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Hash-Tables.html#g-hash-table-new-full) along with [`g_hash_table_remove_all()`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Hash-Tables.html#g-hash-table-remove-all) like this:

```
// Create hash table with default delete callbacks
ht = g_hash_table_new_full(g_direct_hash, g_direct_equal, g_free, g_free);
//                                                        ~~~~~~  ~~~~~~

// Allocate new entry
ds = (DsectionEntity*) malloc( sizeof(DsectionEntity) );

// Populate entry
// ...

// Insert entry in hash table
g_hash_table_insert( ht, 
                     GINT_TO_POINTER( ds->sequence_number ), 
                     (gpointer) ds);

// ^^^ Do check the return value of g_hash_table_insert

// Remove hash table at the end
g_hash_table_remove_all( ht );
```

Check this [example](https://gist.github.com/bert/265933) for your guidance.

---

**Alternative:**

You may want to explore [UT Hash](https://troydhanson.github.io/uthash/) as an alternative hash table solution.